# How do I blur colour borders in Paint.NET

Tags: colors, image-editing, paint.net

I have a document from which I am trying to remove marks. I'm doing so the only way I can, with the colour-picker and the paintbrush, painting over the marks with the closest colour around them. This is all white paper btw, but has wrinkles and smudges etc. When I paint over, I get a streak of nice uniform colour.

I'd like to select that colour and some surrounding colour and somehow blend or merge them. Can I, and if so, how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "Clone stamp" tool for this, (Shortcut key: L).

[image]

> In order to use the clone stamp, you must first choose an area to copy from by clicking an area of the image while pressing the Ctrl key. You may choose a new source area at any time by doing this again.

If you want something more precise, install [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) and use the Healing tool.

[image]